# Report with Contacts with Activities and Opportunities

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports, joined-reports

I am trying to create a report in Salesforce that will display all contacts that have activities and opportunities. Is there any easy way to do this or is it even possible? I tried doing an activities with accounts report since I thought they all linked up, but then I could not get the associated opportunities to display.

Comment: Do you have contact lookup on opportunity object?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by Creating a `Custom Report Type`.

Choose the primary object you’d like your new report type to support, then give it a name and a useful description. Mark it as “in development” until you’re ready to make it available for users to create reports.

Refer the help article for [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5) creation.

Refer the help article for [Add Child Objects to Your Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_report_type_objects.htm&type=5).

Refer the help article for [Design the Field Layout for Reports Created from Your Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_report_type_layouts.htm&type=5).

The custom Report will be look like below.

[image]

If you have `contact lookup` on opportunity object then you can select `primary` object as `Contact` and secondary object as `activities`.

Refer the below screenshot.
[image]

Click on the `edit Layout` as mentioned in the above screenshot and click on `add fields related via lookup` and choose the `opportunity` related fields and then save the layout.

Refer the below screenshot.
[image]

Once you click on the `opportunity`, it will popup window with list of o`pportunity fields`, you can select what are all the fields needed in your report.

[image]

Note:

> Once your report is ready make sure the deployment status should be
> Deployed.

Comment: thanks @AnkaiahBandi this is what I was looking to do.